# CSS dynamic space between elements when element widths are greater than parent width

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have a problem I have solved with Javascript and do not think is possible with just CSS but thought I'd ask since a all CSS solution would be cleaner.

Given the following HTML:

```html
  <div class="items">
    <a class="item">Some Text</a>
    <a class="item">different Text</a>
    ...
  </div>
```

Div `items` has a dynamic width (`width: 100%`) and each `item` will appear in a row; left to right, non-justified. The `width` of each item is determined by the text (ie. `width` is not set) and the exact number of items is unknown (between 5 and 8).

The space between each item is a max of 32px and a min of 8px, They are 32 px if this does not cause the `item`s to exceed the width of the `items` div, if the widths of the `item`s exceed the `items` div the space between each item will dynamically shrink to keep the width of the `item`s less than their parent to a minimum of 8px after which the `item`s will overflow.

Example:
[image]

It's easy to do something like this:

```css
.items {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  margin-right: 32px

  &:last-child { // Cheating and using SCSS syntax but you get the idea
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

This works when the `items` div is large enough to fit everything but I can't figure out how to do the dynamic spacing between with any method (using margin, spacer divs, flex-gap). I can kind of cheat it with `@media` queries but then I'm still hardcoding these limits and its not dynamic based on the items. Since the number of items isn't known and their widths aren't set I'm guessing this is not possible without Javascript.

My final javascript solution was something like the following:

```js
const ro = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
  for (let entry of entries) {
   const items = entry.target
   const itemsWidth = items.clientWidth;
   const children = items.getElementsByClassName('item');

   let itemCount = 0; // Number of Children
   let itemTotalLengths = 0; // Combined length of children
   for (item of children) {
       itemCount += 1;
       itemTotalLengths += item.clientWidth; //Assumes no border
   }
   
   let margin = (itemsWidth - itemTotalLengths)/(itemCount - 1) // Assume itemCount at least 2
   margin = Math.min(32, margin);
   margin = Math.max(8, margin);

   console.log(`setting margin to ${margin}`);
   for (i = 0; i < children.length -1; ++i) {
       const item = children[i];
       item.style.marginRight = `${margin}px`;
   }   
  }
});

// On resize of items
ro.observe(document.getElementsByClassName('items'));
```

This works, but a CSS solution would be preferred if possible. Any insight would be super useful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spacer element should works fine, with the use of `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` you can do the following:

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.spacer {
  flex: 1 1 8px;
  min-width: 8px;
  max-width: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">Info</div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="item">Overview</div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="item">Notes</div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="item">Emails</div>
</div>
```

(Try to resize the window width to see it happen)